# Method to find API call usage

Tags: amazon-mws

I am operating in a production environment with a number of different applications using the Amazon API.  Of these, some are our own home-grown apps, and others are 3rd party shipping applications.

I have a situation where I am hitting an hourly throttle for the Reports API 'GetReport' request, and I am trying to determine what is causing us to be throttled.  By my count, we shouldn't be exceeding ~60 calls per hour at the absolute maximum.  (Just a note, while API info says this function call throttles at 60 requests per hour, the exception I received back indicated a cap of 120 requests per hour.  Maybe the exception is wrong, and I'm hitting a 60 request cap?)

Is there either an API call to determine current call usage, or a method of accessing this information via Amazon Seller Central / Developers Program?  I've done some searching around but everything I can find is describing how the throttling works which isn't my problem.

I am currently using C# Amazon MWS libraries for all function calls, although that information is a bit superfluous.  Any insight into the proper API call to use, or how to gain access to this information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact MWS Support [here](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html) and ask for clarification on your issue.  They surely know of your usage in order to be able to cap it.  I met with the MWS team a few months ago in Detroit and they said any time you have a technical question to ask them.  They've been really helpful to me.

Comment: I'll contact them and see what kind of information I get back.  Basically if I can get total call usage, then shut down 5 of 6 applications and record call usage every 30 minutes, cycle through the apps, I can determine what the source of the high call volume is.  Hopefully they will be able to get me there.

Comment: Amazon MWS support took a few days to get back to me but were able to list my call usage over the past 10 days by application string which pointed me in the right direction for where the problem lies.  Both answers were very valuable, so thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

In the response to most calls you get back something like the following in the response.

```
 "x-mws-quota-max"=>"60.0", 
 "x-mws-quota-remaining"=>"51.0",
 "x-mws-quota-resetsOn"=>"2016-03-25T16:00:00.000Z"
```

You should be able to use this to figure out what is causing you to hit the limit quicker than expected. Perhaps logging out the call and the response with the data above??

Comment: I didn't realize this information was available.  This at minimum will help me avoid hitting the cap.  My biggest issue is I have 4-6 applications that are contributing to the cap, and a couple of them are third part programs so I can't get direct access to how many times they are running the function call.

Comment: I would log the calls and quota info above for everything that you can. If you only have the info from your calls it could possibly show you that the issue is with the 3rd party calls. You could at the very least eliminate your code as the issue. Just a suggestion.

Comment: That will definitely be an upcoming improvement on the reporting system for us.  Currently I am waiting on a response from Amazon MWS to determine if there is a call to actually retrieve the usage, or an administrative page I can access to see the companies call usage (similar to eBay dev network).  I'm trying to minimize the amount of work required to get to the solution as modifying every application that pulls reports is going to take a bit of time.